# Generation of the topology of a vector topological space by a metric

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces

I am trying to prove that the set of equivalence classes of measurable functions with the metric $\rho(f,g)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{|f(x)-g(x)|}{1+|f(x)-g(x)|} \, d\mu$ is a vector topological space.

By definition, a vector topological space is a linear space, with a topology in which addition and multiplication by a scalar are continuous over a set of arguments.

According to the definition, I need to prove that the operations of addition and multiplication by scalar will be continuous. First, I considered multiplication by a scalar: if we take an arbitrary function $f(x)$ and consider the result of multiplication by a scalar $af(x)$, then in order to show continuity, I need to show for any neighborhood $af(x)$ that there exists a neighborhood $f(x)$ such that all functions from this neighborhood, when multiplied by $a$, will fall into the neighborhood of $af(x)$. If $a=0$, then we always get a zero function, so as a neighborhood of $f(x)$ we can take any ball containing $f(x)$. if $a\neq 0$, then for any neighborhood $af(x)$, we can first find a ball centered in $af(x)$ of radius $r$ and try to look for a neighborhood $f(x)$, which, when multiplied by a scalar, will lie entirely in this ball. It seems to me that a ball with a center $f(x)$ of radius $r/a$ should be suitable, because the peculiarity of this metric is that it does not take values greater than or equal to $1$, which means that all the functions that lay in the ball $B(f(x), r/a)$ when multiplied by a should to be in the ball $B(af(x),r)$ from where we get the continuity of multiplication by a scalar.

But there are some difficulties with the continuity of addition: let $h(x) = f(x)+g(x)$. To prove continuity, it must be shown that for any neighborhood $h(x)$ there exist neighborhoods $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that for any elements of these two neighborhoods the sum will lie in the neighborhood $h(x)$. Here again, it seems reasonable to me to find a ball centered in $h(x)$ and try to explicitly construct neighborhoods for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. There is an assumption that balls $B(f(x),r/2)$ and $B(g(x),r/2)$ may be suitable for the ball $B(h(x),r)$ also for reasons that the metric does not take values greater than $1$, but I am not sure about this.

Can you please help me how best to prove the continuity of addition and how correct is my solution for multiplication?

Comment: For multiplication, you want to show that the function $M:\mathbb{K}\times X\to X$ given by $M(a,f)=af$ is continuous. Which means you need to know that for any neighborhood $W$ of $af$, there exist **neighborhoods** $U,V$ of $a$ and $f$, respectively, such that $bg\in W$ for all $b\in U$ and $f\in V$.

Comment: This would definitely be nicer to read if you used LaTeX for all of the math.

Answer (score 0):

The map $(x,y)\mapsto \frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}$ is a metric on the real numbers. Then by triangle inequality
$$
\frac{ |(f_1+g_1)-(f_2+g_2)| }{ 1+ |(f_1+g_1)-(f_2+g_2)|}
\le 
\frac{ |f_1 -f_2|}{1+|f_1-f_2|} 
+
\frac{ |g_1 -g_2|}{1+|g_1-g_2|} .
$$
Now integrate that to obtain
$$
d(f_1+g_1,f_2+g_2) \le d(f_1,f_2) + d(g_1,g_2),
$$
which proves continuity of addition.

Comment: Can you please tell me why out of inequality (1+1,2+2)≤(1,2)+(1,2) should there be continuity for addition? Is there an inequality from which one can obtain the continuity of multiplication by a scalar? Or, for example, is it possible to try to prove inductively: first for natural factors, then for integers, then rational, then real?

Comment: Just basic $\epsilon-\delta$-argument: take $\epsilon>0$  then $d(f_1+g_1,f_2+g_2) < \epsilon$ for all $f_1\dots g_2$ with $d(f_1,f_2)<\epsilon/2$, $ d(g_1,g_2)<\epsilon/2$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!